# How do I adjust the width of a DropDown <select> box?

Tags: html, xhtml

I need to adjust the width of a select HTML box without using css, is there a way? I tried size but then it's adjusting the height, and width does nothing? Is there another way?

Comment: Why are you trying to control the presentation of a webpage without using the presentation language of the web?

Comment: With presentation language you mean CSS? Since I thought maybe I missed some HTML option that is available to use.

Comment: Yes. CSS is the language designed to describe how webpages (and other markup documents) should look. HTML is designed to describe structure, semantics and relationships. It has some (mostly deprecated) presentational stuff left over from the browser wars of the '90s.

Comment: are you hoping to use javascript to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">     
    select {
        width:200px;
    }
</style>
```

Does that not work?

Comment: Looks like I need to stick with inline styles or css

Answer (score 17):

There is no way to do it in pure HTML as per http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6.  You can set it using the style element, though which is kind of without css in that it is inline.

```
<select style="width: ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an empty option with enough spaces in it ...

Comment: This could work if I needed an empty space, thx for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If u using jquery,
    
    Maths
    Physics
    Chemistry

This is my select html code. So u have to add another div which contains jquery class name including your class name and apply height and width in your class.

```
<div class="ui-select selBox"> 
    <select>
    <option>Maths</option>
    <option>Physics</option>
    <option>Chemistry</option>
    </select>
</div>
.selBox{
 width: 470px !important;
 height: 40px !important;
}
```

here selBox is my class name and ui-select is jquery class name.

Comment: Your solution doesn't contain any jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Change the font-size

```
<select name="ships" id="ship-select" class="ships" style="font-size: 2rem;">
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
select
{
    width:  100%;
    height: 42px;
}
```

Add this class to your style tag. It works fine.

Comment: Basically the same solution as the accepted answer from 2009. You have just added an unrelated height parameter.

Comment: As you are a new user this is some guidance on the site.  Please don't answer questions, particularly those with an accepted answer, without reviewing the existing answers and ensuring your answer would bring something new.  You should probably delete this answer.