# How to adjust the width of Html dropdownlist and html editorfor?

Tags: html

I want to align the #'s 5 and 7 specified in the picture. And for the others the # 4 I want to align it in # 3. And if possible the `2.1(First textbox)` will also align in #3?.

Here is the link[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b1Sm.jpg).

Here is the code how I make the date

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FADateTo)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FADateTo)`

For the #1 and #7 text box 
`@Html.DropDownList("ID")`

For the #3

`@Html.DropDownList("ShiftId")`

How to adjust there width?.

**UPDATE**

I try this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411484/how-do-i-adjust-the-width-of-a-dropdown-select-box) and it work but all of my Dropdown has been adjust to the set width. I want to adjust a specific dropdown only.

Comment: you can just use css, write a style on the `input` type, that should solve part of your problem, and then add classes on the rest of them and style those as well. You can also do it in jquery by calculating the widths at runtime or with less or sass by using variables in the style and calculating their values accordingly. So, you have quite a few options. Also bootstrap might help because it gives you a good starting point.

Comment: @Spluf im not good in your suggestions like `css` and `bootstrap`

Comment: for bootstrap go here: http://getbootstrap.com/ and you'll find plenty of useful stuff, also, since you are working on web, you should really consider learning some `css`... it's really easy to learn and it's a serious must for a web developer. After that you can have a look at less or sass to make things better (they compile to css but allows you to use variables and functions in your style). You can find good css courses on pluralsight, w3school or almost anywhere on the web, just do a google search on it.

Comment: @Spluf Okay thanks

Comment: just a final ideea, don't worry about less or sass that much, your work won't look any different, it's just better for maintaining your code afterwards. Focus on css for now, and as a developer, as I said before, bootstrap gives you a great starting point and a lot of useful stuff out of the box... good luck :)